# html div from right to center in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I write this `html/css` code ([link in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ch9qrv7x/))

My images show in right or left side, but i want show in center column.

how to can i done it?

Comment: check if this works http://jsfiddle.net/1ertv89z/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update css and html add a class `text-center` in `row` and remove `float:right` from `div.polaroid`, that's why your image boxes align to right please update css part just like following to get the boxes in center.

Working fiddle also include

**[fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/ch9qrv7x/1/)**

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

div.polaroid {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}

div.polaroid img {
  height: 100px;
}

div.containerq {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body dir="rtl">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row text-center">
      <div class="visible-xs col-xs-12">
        <a href="index3.php?id=9">
          <div class="polaroid">
            <img src="http://anubis.ir/logo.jpg" alt="Norway" style="width:100%">
            <div class="containerq">1</div>
          </div>
        </a>
        <a href="index3.php?id=9">
          <div class="polaroid">
            <img src="http://anubis.ir/logo.jpg" alt="Norway" style="width:100%">
            <div class="containerq">2</div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```